# Netrw tree listing style opening files in other directories creates new empty files in current directory

Tags: netrw

When using netrw with the tree style listing (`netrw_liststyle = 3`), if I expand a directory, open a file in that directory, then try to open a file above that directory, it creates a new empty file in the lower directory with the same name.

For example, I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── baz.txt
└── foo
    ├── bar
    │   └── bar.txt
    └── foo.txt
```

I open the `bar` directory, then `bar.txt`. Then I attempt to open `baz.txt` and instead of opening the file, vim creates an empty file `/foo/bar/baz.txt`.

Is there any way for netrw to know the full paths of the files listed, or does it simply run `:edit` on the file name without the full path?

Edit: I'm using vim 8.0.427 and netrw v156.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on gVim 8.0.69 and netrw v162g. Can you update with version information and also try the [most recent netrw build](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW)?

Comment: how can I check what version of netrw I have?

Comment: `:echo g:loaded_netrw` Should get you the version number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using `:Lexplore` to open the netrw listing and removing the setting `netrw_browse_split = 4` from my .vimrc.

Comment: Glad you were able to get a workaround. However, with `netrw_browse_split = 4` I was able to reproduce the issue. It looks like it might be a bug. I'll mess around with it a bit and might look into submitting a patch to Dr. Chip if it turns out that is the case.